# MSAL ConfidentialClient with workload identity federation

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-msal

Is it possible with the MSAL library (c#) to create a ConfidentialClient which authenticates itself with a [Workload identity federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/workload-identity-federation),
instead of a [secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplicationbuilder.withclientsecret?view=azure-dotnet) or [certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplicationbuilder.withcertificate?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Identity_Client_ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder_WithCertificate_System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2_)?

There does not seem to be an option in the MSAL library for this? [This blog](https://blog.identitydigest.com/azuread-federate-github-actions/) suggests that the library is updated for this scenario, but I cannot find a reference to it.

Scenario would be to use this setup in a github action flow, to run integration tests. In this way, we would not have to use a secret or certificate in the github action flow.

Comment: Based on the given document states that : For a software workload running outside of Azure, you need to use application credentials (a secret or certificate) to access Azure AD protected resources (such as Azure, Microsoft Graph, Microsoft 365, or third-party resources). i think we have to use secret and credential with workload identity federation.

Comment: Yes @Tom De Vree, which you are following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/workload-identity-federation#why-use-workload-identity-federation .

Comment: From the document :
These credentials pose a security risk and have to be stored securely and rotated regularly. You also run the risk of service downtime if the credentials expire.

[workload identity federation] eliminates the maintenance burden of manually managing credentials and eliminates the risk of leaking secrets or having certificates expire.

As i read this, there now is a third option, workload identity federation, to solve the problems of the two other options (secret or certificate).

So I do not think your observation is entirely correct